# how to add a dictionary to array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

I Use from Mongodb and  have a collection like this:

```
{'name':'vahid','visited':[{id:1,'date':'1223123',noskhe:['a','d','h']]}
```

I want an update query to add `{id:2,'date':'324324',noskhe:['d','n']}` to visited array!
How I can get this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator. It will append a new value to the array. Below is the example.

```
db.collection.update({"name":"vahid"},{$push:{ "visited": {id:2,'date':'324324',noskhe:['d','n']}}})
```

Comment: Received pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field 'field_name' must be an array but is of type object in document

Comment: When I try using the push operator (albeit in PyMongo), I get `{TypeError}unhashable type: 'dict'`